# Creating service area using both streets and buslines in same ArcGIS network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, routing, service-area

I want to create a network analysis more difficult. Therefore, I want to calculate a Service Area around hospitals next to bus stops. But: The network does not only consist of roads and pedestrians (time) but also of bus lines and bus stops. In best case the result should be a augmented service area, which includes bus drives to the hospital in a certain time! I nearly have the solution, but here is the problem. Trying to solve the analyse I realized that several bus stops are not within the calculation. I have checked the topology of the stops and lines and there are no errors (as ArcGIS says). Also the attribute table seems to be correct. I tried to planarize the bus lines but I can't use the tool, as it is not possible to click on it (grey color).

Maybe you have a idea to help me?

Problem picture:

[image]

([Source](http://www.students.uni-marburg.de/~Blitza/Facility_Error.jpg))

Comment: Problem solved!
I put the busstations on street junctions and that worked.

Comment: Couldn't you just do a buffer that incorporates bus stops, let's say 400m (0.25 miles)?

Answer (score 2):

The asker "put the busstations on street junctions and that worked".

Although this is a very short Answer I have transferred it from [a comment by the asker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19657/how-to-create-a-service-area-using-both-streets-and-buslines-in-the-same-network?rq=1#comment26592_19657) to assist removal of this resolved issue from our Unanswered questions.